# How to compare the revision of a downloaded file vs Artifactory file

Tags: artifactory, versioning, artifact

I have a deployment artifact stored in the organization JFrog Artifactory. How do I compare the version of the downloaded artifact vs the file in the Artifactory server?

1. I have the option to download the artifact.
2. I have the option to get the info of the artifact in Artifactory.
3. How do I get the version info of the local artifact that was downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

You can use REST API of JFrog artifactory, for example as in JFrog documentation:

```
GET /api/search/versions?[g=groupId][&a=artifactId][&v=version][&remote=0/1][&repos=x[,y]]
```

Sample output:

```
GET /api/search/versions?g=org.acme&a=artifact&repos=libs-release-local
{
"results": [
    {
        "version": "1.2",
        "integration": false
    },{
        "version": "1.0-SNAPSHOT",
        "integration": true
    },{
        "version": "1.0",
        "integration": false
    }
]
}
```

Comment: How would I be able to validate the file in local that was downloaded from the artifactory previously

Comment: I think you can use hash of file from the artifactory and validate with local file.

Comment: But, how would get the hash of the local?

Comment: You can use this API `GET /api/search/checksum?md5=md5sum?sha1=sha1sum?sha256=sha256sum[&repos=x[,y]]`